# How can fix connection string problem in making setup for c# application? (Sql to Express)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I write a program in C# and Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and its work without any problem ...

But when I want make setup file for this app and I make an Express instance of my database that make problem with my connection string.

I copy database files in debug folder and change `app.exe.config` connection string but I get an error.

My program have 5 layer and 4 config file how many of them need change in connection string part ?

I tried this connection string instead of the original connection string , first I tried for the config file in debug folder and its provide error and next time I tried for all config file and its make error too

```
<add name="AccountingDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/AccountingModel.csdl|res://*/AccountingModel.ssdl|res://*/AccountingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AccountingDB.MDF;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Error:

> unhandled exception has occurred in your application. if you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue, if you click quit, the application will close immediately.

Some of details :

> See the end of this message for details on invoking 
>   just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Unable to open the physical file "E:\Projects\Programing Project\C#\Accounting1.0\UI\bin\Debug\AccountingDB.MDF". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
>
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Projects\Programing  Project\C#\Accounting1.0\UI\bin\Debug\AccountingDB.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()

Comment: Have you read exception? It states that access is denied

Comment: @Y.Y. actually its too much to read for who not so good at English ... but any way what's wrong here what should I do??

Comment: This text: Unable to open the physical file "E:\Projects\Programing Project\C#\Accounting1.0\UI\bin\Debug\AccountingDB.MDF". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"  You have to give necessary rights for access to file AccountingDB.MDF

Comment: @Y.Y. sorry I forgot say thanks for your help ... its works ... I go to SQL and give that instance all rights ...

Comment: Ok. It's good to hear. You can votes my answer :)